# GNU GRUB v2.02 on System restore on Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I just bought an MSI 15.6" GS60 Ghost Pro from craigslist seller. Everything works well until I paid him and Restored it to factory setting. What's happening now is that I'm getting this:

```
GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-29utuntu0.3  
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. 
Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.  
grub>
```

I've tried entering a bunch of codes that i read from other users who have similar problem but all with the same error message such as:

```
find /grub/stage2  
geometry (hd0)  
e
```

```
error: can't find command 'e'
```

I think the original spec is something like this [MSI GS60 GHOST PRO 3K](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JSA1PH0). I don't have a Boot CD for this Windows 10 laptop. So what do i do? Please help.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can get Windows installation media from the Microsoft website, maybe the computer manufacturer does supply them as well.

If you just want a working computer and dont care about the operating system, you could just download Ubuntu and select "delete everything and install Ubuntu".

Answer (score 0):

What has probably happened is that you no longer have grub/stage2.  Your have eliminated the partitions which were installed for dual boot, when you went back to Factory settings.

However, you can probably easily boot into windows.  You still have grub (apparently).

First, you can list the partitions on your machine:

```
grub> ls
```

You will probably see something like (hd0, msdos1) (hd0, msdos2)

Then, you can type something like the following at the grub prompt

```
set root=(hd0,msdos2)
chainloader +1
boot
```

(you can experiment with the various partitions -- on my Windows 7 machine, msdos1 goes into a diagnostics boot)

Now, if this gets you into Windows, you can use it temporarily (or permanently) to boot your machine. If it doesn't, you could make a grub rescue disk, giving you a more completely functioning grub.  This would be a dvd, cd, or flash drive.  It would boot into a grub which would have additional modules (like "insmod ntfs").

Then, you have two choices.  You can learn about Windows Repair, which probably has a way to rewrite the boot-strap loader -- but be careful, because it will overwrite grub.

The other choice is to make space for Ubuntu on your hard drive (by reducing the size of your partition) -- I would use "Computer Management" tools in Windows to resize your main partition. You don't need much space to have a minimal Ubuntu -- see the installation notes.

Then, you can install Ubuntu, which will give you a dual boot system, working grub and grub stage 2 which will allow you to boot into Windows more gracefully.

Additional useful commands for grub are:

```
set pager=1
help
```